# The tag "beats_input_codec_plain_applied" present in every document in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have set up the ELK stack with the version 7.2.0 : filebeat, logstash, elasticsearch & kibana.

When I send my logs to Kibana, I can see a tag "beats_input_codec_plain_applied" in every document.

I search through internet but there is no explanation about why this tag is added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be undocumented, but this tag is added to every beats message by logstash `beats` input, it shows which codec was applied to the beats message, in your case it is the `plain` codec.

You can remove it in the logstash pipeline using a `mutate` filter.

```
mutate {
    remove_tag => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied"]
}
```

Or you can disable it in the input configuration by setting the option [`include_codec_tag`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html#plugins-inputs-beats-include_codec_tag) to `false`.

```
input {
    beats {
        ... your beats input config ...
        include_codec_tag => false
    }
}
```